# Handling MouseDownEvent of ToggleButton in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mouseevent, togglebutton, addhandler

I'm trying to handle the MouseDownEvent for this control by adding a hook to RootVisual:

```
Application.Current.RootVisual.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, 
(MouseButtonEventHandler)OnMouseLeftButtonEvent, true);
```

But even though I set the last parameter to true, it doesn't trigger for some reason. Any ideas on why is this happening and how to fix this are welcome!

EDIT: this toggle is located in a popup window if it makes any difference.